# Magento 2.2.2 Upgrade to 2.2.6 Not Latest

Tags: magento2, php, apache

I want to upgrade a magento 2.2.2 site to 2.2.6 mainly to fix issues with very slow reindex esp for Catalog Search index when Elasticsearch is being used

I dont want to upgrade to the latest 2.3.2 version as there a alot of issues with various extensions

Please can someone let me know how this can be done with the little amount of fuss - Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run cli commands to upgrade:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 --no-update
composer update
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Comment: thank you will run it